# Can I restore an MSDB.bak as a non-system database without affecting the active MSDB?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to restore a backup of MSDB as a normal database to look at some old settings.

I only have one database at the version required to restore the backup, so I can't really test, but I'm trying to determine if restoring this database will cause any undesirable effects in the active MSDB.

When I tried to restore to different, slightly newer versions I get the error: "The backup of the system database on the device  cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (13.00.4199) than this server (13.00.4206)."

Is it possible to do this without causing any problems with the active MSDB?

SQL Server 2016

Comment: Try it? You are on a test server right? You are going to restore this backup to a database with a different name right?

Comment: @Sean Lange Unfortunately, I only have a prod instance at that version. But yes, I'd use a different name.

Comment: Well I would argue that having only prod at a certain version is a major problem. How can you support that type of environment and be successful? Try it on another server using that msdb backup. Or standup another instance of 2016 and try it out.

Comment: I guess the point I am trying to make is that production is NOT the place for testing stuff like this. What happens if I tell you "sure go for it, it won't be an issue at all" and then you restore it in production only to have your entire instance hosed? I doubt the management types will care that some dude on the internet said it should work. They are going to be mad that their production sql server needs a complete rebuild.

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed. Spinning up a test environment now.

Comment: Now that sounds like a mighty fine plan. I know the answer but curious what you find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question, yes it is possible to restore a backup of MSDB as a non-system database without affecting the active MSDB. I used the T-SQL below, but the SSMS GUI can accomplish the same.

```
restore database MsdbTest from disk = '<DriveLetter>:\<PathToBackup>\msdb.bak'
with
    move 'MSDBData' to '<DriveLetter>:\<Path>\MsdbTest.mdf',
    move 'MSDBLog' to '<DriveLetter>:<Path>\MsdbTest.ldf'
```